# Linked list vs dynamic array for implementing a stack using vector class

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list, stack, dynamic-arrays

I was reading up on the two different ways of implementing a stack: linked list and dynamic arrays. The main advantage of a linked list over a dynamic array was that the linked list did not have to be resized while a dynamic array had to be resized if too many elements were inserted hence wasting alot of time and memory.

That got me wondering if this is true for C++ (as there is a vector class which automatically resizes whenever new elements are inserted)?

Comment: Most dynamic arrays double in size (of the backing array) when the load factor is around 60-70% (full). Using that schema of growing, it minimizes the wasted time, reallocating and moving memory. I don't know the particular details of C++ vector class though.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409756/linked-list-vs-dynamic-array-for-implementing-a-stack?rq=1

Comment: *"hence wasting alot of time and memory"* It not so much that a lot of time is used (because it is amortized constant time) but that the time cost is paid in big chunks when resize and copy operation occur. Memory wise, depending on the multiplier you use (it need not be two and 1.4 or 1.5 are not uncommon) and the payload size in the linked list the dynamic array may be competitive in wasted space.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's difficult to compare the two, because the patterns of their memory usage are quite different.

**Vector resizing**

A vector resizes itself dynamically as needed. It does that by allocating a new chunk of memory, moving (or copying) data from the old chunk to the new chunk, the releasing the old one. In a typical case, the new chunk is 1.5x the size of the old (contrary to popular belief, 2x seems to be quite unusual in practice). That means for a short time while reallocating, it needs memory equal to roughly 2.5x as much as the data you're actually storing. The rest of the time, the "chunk" that's in use is a minimum of 2/3<sup>rds</sup> full, and a maximum of completely full. If all sizes are equally likely, we can expect it to average about 5/6<sup>ths</sup> full. Looking at it from the other direction, we can expect about 1/6<sup>th</sup>, or about 17% of the space to be "wasted" at any given time.

When we do resize by a constant *factor* like that (rather than, for example, always adding a specific size of chunk, such as growing in 4Kb increments) we get what's called amortized constant time addition. In other words, as the array grows, resizing happens exponentially less often. The average number of times items in the array have been copied tends to a constant (usually around 3, but depends on the growth factor you use).

**linked list allocations**

Using a linked list, the situation is rather different. We never see resizing, so we don't see extra time or memory usage for some insertions. At the same time, we *do* see extra time and memory used essentially *all* the time. In particular, each node in the linked list needs to contain a pointer to the next node. Depending on the size of the data in the node compared to the size of a pointer, this can lead to significant overhead. For example, let's assume you need a stack of `int`s. In a typical case where an `int` is the same size as a pointer, that's going to mean 50% overhead -- all the time. It's increasingly common for a pointer to be *larger* than an `int`; twice the size is fairly common (64-bit pointer, 32-bit int). In such a case, you have ~67% overhead -- i.e., obviously enough, each node devoting twice as much space to the pointer as the data being stored.

Unfortunately, that's often just the tip of the iceberg. In a typical linked list, each node is dynamically allocated individually. At least if you're storing small data items (such as `int`) the memory allocated for a node may be (usually will be) even larger than the amount you actually request. So -- you ask for 12 bytes of memory to hold an int and a pointer -- but the chunk of memory you get is likely to be rounded up to 16 or 32 bytes instead. Now you're looking at overhead of at least 75% and quite possibly ~88%.

As far as speed goes, the situation is rather similar: allocating and freeing memory dynamically is often quite slow. The heap manager typically has blocks of free memory, and has to spend time searching through them to find the block that's most suited to the size you're asking for. Then it (typically) has to split that block into two pieces, one to satisfy your allocation, and another of the remaining memory it can use to satisfy other allocations. Likewise, when you free memory, it typically goes back to that same list of free blocks and checks whether there's an adjoining block of memory already free, so it can join the two back together.

Allocating and managing lots of blocks of memory is expensive.

**cache usage**

Finally, with recent processors we run into another important factor: cache usage. In the case of a vector, we have all the data right next to each other. Then, after the end of the part of the vector that's in use, we have some empty memory. This leads to excellent cache usage -- the data we're using gets cached; the data we're not using has little or no effect on the cache at all.

With a linked list, the pointers (and probable overhead in each node) are distributed throughout our list. I.e., each piece of data we care about has, right next to it, the overhead of the pointer, and the empty space allocated to the node that we're not using. In short, the *effective* size of the cache is reduced by about the same factor as the overall overhead of each node in the list -- i.e., we might easily see only 1/8<sup>th</sup> of the cache storing the date we care about, and 7/8<sup>ths</sup> devoted to storing pointers and/or pure garbage.

**Summary**

A linked list can work well when you have a relatively small number of nodes, each of which is individually quite large. If (as is more typical for a stack) you're dealing with a relatively large number of items, each of which is individually quite small, you're *much* less likely to see a savings in time or memory usage. Quite the contrary, for such cases, a linked list is much more likely to basically waste a great deal of both time and memory.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, what you say is true for C++. For this reason, the default container inside [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack), which is the standard stack class in C++, is neither a vector nor a linked list, but a double ended queue (a `deque`). This has nearly all the advantages of a vector, but it resizes much better.

Basically, an [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) is a *linked list of arrays*  of sorts internally. This way, when it needs to resize, it just adds another array.

Comment: so std:stack is different from the vector class?

Comment: Yes. `std::stack` is not really a container, but a container adaptor which is implemented using a container inside it. By default it uses a `std::deque`, but you can use any container. `std::vector` is a true container. You can have a `std::stack` that uses a `std::vector` internally, but the interface will be different.

Answer (score 2):

First, the performance trade-offs between linked-lists and dynamic arrays are a lot more subtle than that.

The vector class in C++ is, by requirement, implemented as a "dynamic array", meaning that it must have an amortized-constant cost for inserting elements into it. How this is done is usually by increasing the "capacity" of the array in a geometric manner, that is, you double the capacity whenever you run out (or come close to running out). In the end, this means that a reallocation operation (allocating a new chunk of memory and copying the current content into it) is only going to happen on a few occasions. In practice, this means that the overhead for the reallocations only shows up on performance graphs as little spikes at logarithmic intervals. This is what it means to have "amortized-constant" cost, because once you neglect those little spikes, the cost of the insert operations is essentially constant (and trivial, in this case).

In a linked-list implementation, you don't have the overhead of reallocations, however, you do have the overhead of allocating each new element on freestore (dynamic memory). So, the overhead is a bit more regular (not spiked, which can be needed sometimes), but could be more significant than using a dynamic array, especially if the elements are rather inexpensive to copy (small in size, and simple object). In my opinion, linked-lists are only recommended for objects that are really expensive to copy (or move). But at the end of the day, this is something you need to test in any given situation.

Finally, it is important to point out that locality of reference is often the determining factor for any application that makes extensive use and traversal of the elements. When using a dynamic array, the elements are packed together in memory one after the other and doing an in-order traversal is very efficient as the CPU can preemptively cache the memory ahead of the reading / writing operations. In a vanilla linked-list implementation, the jumps from one element to the next generally involves a rather erratic jumps between wildly different memory locations, which effectively disables this "pre-fetching" behavior. So, unless the individual elements of the list are very big and operations on them are typically very long to execute, this lack of pre-fetching when using a linked-list will be the dominant performance problem.

As you can guess, I rarely use a linked-list (`std::list`), as the number of advantageous applications are few and far between. Very often, for large and expensive-to-copy objects, it is often preferable to simply use a vector of pointers (you get basically the same performance advantages (and disadvantages) as a linked list, but with less memory usage (for linking pointers) and you get random-access capabilities if you need it).

The main case that I can think of, where a linked-list wins over a dynamic array (or a segmented dynamic array like `std::deque`) is when you need to frequently insert elements in the middle (not at either ends). However, such situations usually arise when you are keeping a sorted (or ordered, in some way) set of elements, in which case, you would use a tree structure to store the elements (e.g., a binary search tree (BST)), not a linked-list. And often, such trees store their nodes (elements) using a semi-contiguous memory layout (e.g., a breadth-first layout) within a dynamic array or segmented dynamic array (e.g., a cache-oblivious dynamic array).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's true for `C++` or any other language. Dynamic array is **a concept**. The fact that C++ has `vector` doesn't change the theory. The vector in `C++` actually does the resizing internally so this task isn't the developers' responsibility. The actual cost doesn't magically disappear when using `vector`, it's simply offloaded to the standard library implementation.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` is implemented using a dynamic array, whereas `std::list` is implemented as a linked list. There are trade-offs for using both data structures. Pick the one that best suits your needs.

- As you indicated, a dynamic array can take a larger amount of time adding an item if it gets full, as it has to expand itself. However, it is faster to access since all of its members are grouped together in memory. This tight grouping also usually makes it more cache-friendly.
- Linked lists don't need to resize ever, but traversing them takes longer as the CPU must jump around in memory.

Answer (score 0):

> That got me wondering if this is true for c++ as there is a vector class which automatically resizes whenever new elements are inserted.

Yes, it still holds, because a `vector` resize is a potentially expensive operation. Internally, if the pre-allocated size for the vector is reached and you attempt to add new elements, a new allocation takes place and the old data is moved to the new memory location.

Answer (score 0):

From [the C++ documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/):

> vector::push_back - Add element at the end
>
> Adds a new element at the end of the vector, after its current last element. The content of val is copied (or moved) to the new element.
>
> This effectively increases the container size by one, which causes an automatic reallocation of the allocated storage space if -and only if- the new vector size surpasses the current vector capacity.

Answer (score 0):

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style
Skip to 44:40. You should prefer `std::vector` whenever possible over a `std::list`, as explained in the video, by Bjarne himself. Since `std::vector` stores all of it's elements next to each other, in memory, and because of that it will have the advantage of being cached in memory. And this is true for adding and removing elements from `std::vector` and also searching. He states that `std::list` is 50-100x slower than a `std::vector`.

If you really want a stack, you should really use `std::stack` instead of making your own.

Comment: so std::vector is different from std::stack ?

Comment: In C++ `std::stack` is implemented as an adaptor, so that you can pass it a container and it will make it work as a stack. By default, `std::deque` is used. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/